# Equivalent terms of LLVM IR for watermarking by renumbering?

Tags: security, llvm, obfuscation, watermark, llvm-ir

I want to apply an algorithm for watermarking that basically reorders equivalent terms of a programming language:

https://books.google.dk/books?id=mig-bH3u0Z0C&pg=PT595&lpg=PT595&dq=obfuscation+renumbering+register&source=bl&ots=b3vMhp-yTq&sig=RERdnDNewRqBi7ZmSNMlsnPy-Hw&hl=da&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiLw-zWrpnSAhWEHJoKHXCpAkMQ6AEIGTAA#v=onepage&q=obfuscation%20renumbering%20register&f=false

Say,  `T1, T2,...,Tn` are equivalent terms of the language, then the watermark is a permutation `f` such that `f(Ti) = Tj`.

In this case the programming language is LLVM IR, which is an intermediate language.

The book gives an example of renumbering registers by applying a permutation. However, registers are not in the scope of LLVM IR, since they are a lower-level detail?

I've been thinking of equivalent terms of LLVM, but cannot come up with some. The more the better, since this means a more flexible degree of watermarking.

Can you think of equivalent terms of LLVM IR such that each could be substituted for some other? Or is it only possible to do such watermarking at the machine code level?

Answer (score 0):

Even if you perform this at the IR level (and you could by changing patterns), you won't get far since the machine instruction level would reshuffle everything. You better off writing a (potentially post-RA) machine instruction level pass.

Comment: Thanks Joky. What is "post-RA"? How would I write a machine instruction pass? Is this possible using LLVM framework? Could you point me in the direction on how to do this?

Comment: post-RA means after register-allocation. Here is the doc: http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html#the-machinefunctionpass-class ; and I advise you to search in the LLVM codebase for MachineFunctionPass to see multiple examples of it.